# using modal box for file upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my MVC application am allowing the user to upload a file. Whenever user clicks on upload file link this is the link

```
  <a class="upload" onclick="upload(this);">
```

the file upload should get open in modal box.

```
function upload(box) {
       var box = dhtmlx.modalbox({
           title: "Upload File",
           text: "<div id='form_in_box'><div>Choose a PDF file to upload <hr/><label>Enter the URL <input type='file' name='file' id='file' style='width: 400px; height: 27px;'></label><br></div><div><span class='dhtmlx_button'><input type='submit' value='Upload File' style='width: 86px' onclick='save_file(this)'></span><span class='dhtmlx_button'><input type='button' value='Cancel' onclick='close_file(this)' style='width:80px;'></span></label></div></div>",
           width: "300px"
       });
   }
   function close_file(box) {

       dhtmlx.modalbox.hide(box);

   }

   function save_file(box) {
       var file = $("#file").val();
       if (file == "") {
           alert("Enter the URL");
           return false;

       dhtmlx.modalbox.hide(box);
       dhtmlx.message("Uploading the file");
       $.post("/FileUpload/Upload",
       { file: '' + file + '' });
   }
  and the controller code is 
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        SaveFile(file);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

but the problem is am getting error i.e. file = null

Comment: In your controller action check if the `Request.Form["file"]` has anything

Comment: Does file variable in ajax post request has data in it. Try debugging your script and check if `file` has any data when sending a post request to the controller

Comment: while debugging only i found file = null

Comment: on clientside or on serverside ?

Comment: place a `debugger;` after `var file = $("#file").val();` and check if the variable file has anything in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot upload files using an AJAX request (`$.post`). If your browser supports the HTML5 File API you could use the new [`XHR2 object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications). If not, you could use a file upload plugin such as [`Uploadify`](http://www.uploadify.com/), [`Fine Uploader`](http://fineuploader.com/) or [`PLUpload`](http://www.plupload.com/). All those plugins will detect whether the client browser supports the HTML5 File API and use it if so and if it doesn't they will fallback to standard techniques such as using hidden iframes or Flash movies. The advantage of using one of them is that you don't need to be coding for all the possible cases.

Here's an example of how you could upload the file using the HTML5 File API:

```
function save_file(box) {
    var file = document.getElementById('file');
    if (file.value == '') {
        alert('Enter the URL');
        return false;
    }

    dhtmlx.modalbox.hide(box);
    dhtmlx.message('Uploading the file');

    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file.files[0]);
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/FileUpload/Upload', true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            alert('file successfully uploaded to the server');
        }
    };
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```